Neovim LSP disable vim.lsp.buf.signature_help() default key binding CTRL-S
I use the vim-rails plugin to edit .erb files.
In VIM in the insert mode, I could use a shortcut CTRL-s + = to insert <%= %> block, as shown here. But in NeoVim this keymapping CTRL-s is used by default by vim.lsp.buf.signature_help() function

The NeoVim LSP documentation says that this default mapping can be disabled by:
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('LspAttach', {
  callback = function(ev)
    vim.bo[ev.buf].formatexpr = nil
    vim.bo[ev.buf].omnifunc = nil
    vim.keymap.del('i', '<C-s>', { buffer = ev.buf })
  end,
})

But when it is added to my NeoVim config I got the following error:
Error detected while processing function <lambda>23[1]..<SNR>243_GetCapabilitiesResult[3]..<SNR>243_LspRequest[1]..LspAttach Autocommands for "*":
Error executing lua callback: vim/keymap.lua:0: E31: No such mapping 

How to disable this keymapping CTRL-s for vim.lsp.buf.signature_help() and keep it working for the rails-vim plugin?
